# How can i make like this dots widget in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, widget

I have a task, and i need to build like this dots. can anyone help me?

[image]
[image]
[image]

i try use alot of packeges but i didn't get the same result of pictures

Comment: https://pub.dev/packages/smooth_page_indicator Try this package and reduce height you will achieve same output as you want

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [SmoothPageIndicator](https://pub.dev/packages/smooth_page_indicator) package and this code to implement something like your pictures:

```
SmoothPageIndicator(
  controller: controller, //pass your page controller
  count: 3,
  effect:  ExpandingDotsEffect(
      activeDotColor: Colors.yellow[800]!,
      dotWidth: 6,
      dotHeight: 6,
      expansionFactor: 5,
      dotColor: Colors.grey),
),
```

The result:
[image]